# How to use PlotRange with GeoGraphics

Tags: plotting, geographics

I am using PlotRange to clip a GeoGraphics plot so that I can center an area of interest.  However, I do this via trial-and-error because I have no idea how PlotRange coordinates specified as `PlotRange->{{-0.4,.6},{-.25,.4}}` which properly clips the geographic result.

But, what am I doing?  In an ordinary coordinate plotted graph I am controlling the range of the coordinate axis over the plotted range of values.  But in a GeoGraphics plot it seems that the maximum range of these coordinates is plus and minus 1 for each axis (horizontal and vertical).

This a guess because there is no documentation under PlotRange that describes how it is being used with a GeoGraphics plot.  And, under GeoGraphics documentation, there is no explicit mention of PlotRange.

Question: what is the meaning of the numeric values specified in PlotRange coordinate limits.  Are they fractions of a whole projection and if so do they measure anything (certainly not longitude and latitude lines that I can tell).

Comment: The option is `GeoRange` and the documentation for `GeoGraphics` states `Use GeoRange to define the latitude and longitude coordinate ranges` and gives examples of its use.

Comment: Are you saying that PlotRange should not be used.  Because it does what I want it to do (set clipping rectangle) but I just wanted an explanation of how it worked with GeoGraphics.

Comment: If you are working with `GeoGraphics` the "natural" and intuitive method to specify range is lat/long. You expressed difficulty (trial-and-error) with `PlotRange` and I suggested that you avoid this difficulty.

Comment: As @BobHanlon mentioned, you actually want to use `GeoRange` rather than `PlotRange` for `GeoGraphics` as this is what the documentation suggests. However it seems that in 12.1, `GeoRange` and `PlotRange` do almost same thing for `GeoGraphics`, but the X and Y is reversed - it is `{{-lat, +lat}, {-lon, +lon}}` for `PlotRange` and `{{-lon, +lon}, {-lat, +lat}}` for `GeoRange`. Also, you might want to use `GeoCenter` to centre your `GeoGraphics` (and using `GeoRangePadding` to add to your view range), rather than moving `PlotRange` or `GeoRange` about.

Comment: @BobHanlon  I just tried GeoRange with a variety of lat/long intervals to basically include mainland US.  I am actually plotting all the states (except, HI and AK), resulting in mainland US but specifically mainland US country is not one of the entities being plotted.    In using GeoRange, the graph of the US never appears enclosed within a bounded region.  I even attempted to use lat/long intervals that were inside the dimensions of continental US and it still did not do the expected.

Comment: Furthermore you may want to use `GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]` rather than manually setting bounds, and setting `GeoRangePadding -> None` to prevent an automatic padding.

Comment: @CarlLange I am using GeoCenter but I will experiment with GeoRangePadding.  Note that PlotRange is easy once you find the right coordinates but I have no idea why those coordinates are working as they do.  This is the reason for my question -- why does PlotRange work in this fashion?

Comment: @CarlLange  Your suggestion worked, using both GeoRange on the Entity for the US and GeoRangePadding->None worked.  It is not exactly the same as before which was near perfect but it is acceptable.  If this were an actual answer instead of a comment I would accept it as the solution.

Comment: I will add it as an answer and add some extra details.

Comment: By the way, I found this example of a geograph similar to what I wanted to do so I used it as a model for my approach.  You will note that it uses PlotRange and this is why I used it but that was after my attempts of other geo methods were not working right.  Link: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1671437

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @BobHanlon mentioned, you actually want to use `GeoRange` rather than `PlotRange` for `GeoGraphics` as this is what the documentation suggests. Also, you might want to use `GeoCenter` to centre your `GeoGraphics` (and using `GeoRangePadding` to add to your view range, or `GeoRangePadding -> None` to set the default padding off), rather than moving `PlotRange` or `GeoRange` about.

One of the more useful things about using the `Geo*` functions is that most of them work correctly with geographic entities, so you can also do `GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"]` which is often more useful than setting it to specific lat/lon ranges.

Anyway, *if the projection is equirectangular*, `GeoRange` and `PlotRange` do almost same thing for `GeoGraphics`, but the X and Y is reversed - it is `{{-lon, +lon}, {-lat, +lat}}` for `PlotRange` and `{{-lat, +lat}, {-lon, +lon}}` for GeoRange. In both cases `lat` and `lon` are absolute angular degrees by default.

**However**, if the projection for your `GeoGraphics` is *not* equirectangular, `PlotRange` will use the native units for your projection, which is nearly always confusing and not what you want. This is a big reason to use `GeoRange` instead of `GeoGraphics`, especially as `GeoGraphics` will automatically change projections based on the size of the range by default.

```
GeoGraphics[PlotRange -> {{-10, -6}, {53, 56}}, 
 GeoGridLines -> Quantity[.1, "AngularDegrees"], GeoProjection -> "Equirectangular"]
```

[image]

```
GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> {{53, 56}, {-10, -6}}, 
 GeoGridLines -> Quantity[.1, "AngularDegrees"]]
```

[image]